# Чи може бути у реченні декілька варіантів розташування розділових знаків

Tags: пунктуація

> Життя прожити потоптати сум єством своїм прославити людину! (А. М'ястківський)

Автор розставив розділові знаки наступним чином

> Життя прожити — потоптати сум, єством своїм прославити людину!

І ось у мене питання, чи буде наступне речення правильним з точки зору пунктуації?

> Життя прожити, потоптати сум єством своїм — прославити людину!

Я вважаю, що це речення також буде вірним, якщо вважати, що `життя прожити` це головне речення, а `потоптати сум єством своїм` — підрядне. Чи буде помилкою такий запис?

Comment: Чи намагалися Ви самотужки знайти розв'язок?

Comment: Так, i я вважаю, що тут декiлька варiантiв

Comment: Напишіть їх тоді в питання, уявіть, що ви самі намагаєтеся відповісти на власне питання. Що за оригінал(з посиланнями)? Ваші варіанти(в ідеалі з поясненнями чому такі варіанти)? Навіщо вам інший варіант? І т.д. і т.п. Люди не вміють читати ваші думки. Почитайте [як ставити гарні питання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ви ж не перший раз ставите питання в мережі SE.

Comment: @Евгений, річ у тім, що в цього сайту є певне призначення. Він **не** призначений для _точкової_ допомоги окремим відвідувачам (тим паче з навчальними завданнями); натомість запитання мають бути написані так, щоб **знайти їх і скористатися відповідями на них потім могли безліч інших відвідувачів**. Я рекомендую:

Comment: 1. Обмежити запитання. Ви питаєте про всі можливі комбінації розділових знаків (за умови, що ми, припустімо, не знаємо оригінальної пунктуації вірша й вкладеного його автором змісту)? Чи конкретно про тире після «прожити» — обґрунтування його обов'язковості/необов'язковості, можливі альтернативи (за умови, що ми, припустімо, знаємо, що саме мав на увазі автор, і хочемо приблизно зберегти суть)? Чи щось інше?

Comment: 2. Дати точніший заголовок. Адже читачу із заголовку нічого не зрозуміло, окрім того, що запитання стосується розділових знаків / пунктуації (але це видно й із теґів). Варто б конкретизувати, наприклад, «обґрунтування для тире / альтернативи до тире в <таких-то випадках>» абощо.

Comment: 3. Озвучити процес власних пошуків: що саме Ви знайшли й на чому зупинилися.

Comment: Просто для інформації: [це вірш (чи уривок з вірша)](//books.google.com/books?id=x3JgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22укласти+труд%22) Андрія М'ястківського: «Життя прожити — це Вітчизну всю // до серця взяти гордо, як святиню, — // її вогонь, простори і красу, // укласти труд свій у її твердиню! //// Життя прожити — потоптати сум, // єством своїм прославити Людину!»

Comment: @Sasha виправив питання

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Звичайно, багато речень дозволяють різні варіанти простановки розділових знаків (але це може впливати на значеня чи конотацію).

У наведеному варіанті, по-моєму, обидва варіанти мають право на існування. Я особисто сприймаю:

- > Життя прожити — потоптати сум, єством своїм прославити людину!

  як

  > «Життя прожити» означає «потоптати сум і єством своїм прославити людину».
- > Життя прожити, потоптати сум єством своїм — прославити людину!

  як

  > «Життя прожити й потоптати сум єством своїм» означає «прославити людину».

— хоча можливі різні інтерпретації (не лише з «означає»).

Адже кома й особливо тире можуть відігравати різні ролі, тому навіть при одних і тих самих розділових знаках на тих самих позиціях речення теоретично може бути сприйнято різними людьми по-різному.

<sub>P. S.: До чого тут *підрядне*, я не зовсім розумію. Мені знається, для підрядності мають використовуватися певні сполучники. А якщо просто кома, то це радше однорідні або одне із них вставне.</sub>